# What is this Thinkpad keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Thinkpad X1 Carbon (2015?). What layout is this, and are there any peculiarities about using it?

I notice for example that Shift, Alt, Ctrl, Del, PG up, PG down, etc are not spelled out, but rather in pictograms.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard. It then has some extra power keys (function keys), which will (usually) be specific to that manufacturer.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QWERTY_keyboard_language_variants#Canadian_Multilingual_Standard).

P.S. Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_X1_series) page to understand the age of the machine